# Shifting an image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph

I am creating a series of figures of a world map using data on marine heatwaves. I would like my figures to shift slighly to the right, to avoid Africa being segmented into two pieces.

Here is one of my [figures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsCsM.jpg)

I tried using `setm`, but I believe it requires a package that I was unable to find. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your image is a normal matrix, so you can reorganize the columns

```
% take this matlab-example (just load it like this)
img = imread('peppers.png');

col_shft = 100;
% its a RGB, i.e. 3D image
img_shft = [img(:,col_shft:end,:),img(:,1:col_shft-1,:)];

% display results
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(img)
subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(img_shft)
```

BTW, if you assign the shifted image direclty to the variable of the original image, i.e.

```
img = [img(:,col_shft:end,:),img(:,1:col_shft-1,:)];
```

than it won't affect you memory much